# Return multiple data independent resource promises

Tags: angularjs, api, angular-promise, angular-resource

Via this link I've found an example of returning multiple resource promises (lines 44-52):

http://embed.plnkr.co/LZad4ZyEYjrbKiTPbAwu/script.js

```
var GistsData = Gists.query();
var MetaData = Meta.get();

GistsData.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 1 data loaded!')});
MetaData.$promise.then(function(response) {console.log('Resource 2 data loaded!')});

return $q.all([GistsData.$promise, MetaData.$promise]);
```

In my case the second resource API call (MetaData) is dependent on a specific value that is returned by the first resource API call (GistsData).

I try to figure out how I can use a value that is returned by GistData (for example an ID) in the MetaData resource? Like this:

```
var MetaData = Meta.get({ id : GistsData.id });
```

I want to return a promise after the MetaData with the ID has returned a promise.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suggest you do a little more reading about promises, as they are awesome :)

As for your question, what you want to do is promise chaining. Notice how you are utilising the `.then()` functions for each of the resource promises. `then()` gets called once the promise has resolved, which in your case is when the queries have returned.

So instead of running each one independently, use the `then()` function of the first promise to then begin running the second. For example:

```
return Gists.query().$promise.then(function(response){
    // Gists has finished and the data it returned is in response
    // Now run your second query, using the response from the first

    return Meta.get({ id : response.id }).$promise.then(function(nextResponse){

        // Now nextResponse will contain the result of Meta.get(), having used the id that returned from the first response
        console.log(nextResponse);
    });
});
```

Now there are nicer ways to write the above, but hopefully it explains chaining enough for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Since I'm using 'resolve' it expects me to return a promise. I want to return a promise that contains data from both calls, is that possible?

Comment: Yeah. I have updated the answer. You simply return the promise that is returned by `then()`, and it will resolve once the chain has completed. This is the whole point of promises.

Comment: Also note that you need to return the internal promise as well.